# Telerik RadGridView custom sorting event only sorts ascending

Tags: c#, sorting, telerik, radgridview

I'm trying to sort a `Telerik RadGridView` by column header click. For this I'm using `Custom_Sorting()` event. I found **[this documenation post](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-sorting-custom-sorting.html)** about that event.

My code is the following:

```
private void radGridView1_CustomSorting(object sender, GridViewCustomSortingEventArgs e)
{
    decimal priority1 = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row1.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString());
    decimal priority2 = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row2.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString());

    if (priority1 > priority2)
    {
        e.SortResult = 1;
    }

    else if (priority1 < priority2)
    {
        e.SortResult = -1;
    }

    else
    {
        e.SortResult = 0;
    }
}
```

My problem is, that it only sorts ascending or none. It never sorts descending. I cannot figure out why.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** It's a WinForms application.

Comment: What edition of rad controls do you have?

Comment: Q3 2014. There is no update available for me

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal may not be succeeding check your prtority1 and 2 to see if they are what you excpect try a normal cast (Decimal)

Comment: They are. I debugged it and they are exactly what they should be... They are the correct values of the cells

Comment: remove of the .tostring() part

Comment: `(decimal)e.Row1.Cells["priority"].Value;` don't help :/ and removing `.ToString()` didn't help neither..

Comment: is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: WinForms. I'll put that into my question

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not taking into account the sortorder.

Use this line to decide whether the sortorder is ascending or descending:

```
var sortOrder = radGridView1.Columns["priority"].SortOrder;
```